# How to sum a count of bookings to display total bookings for location and total value for location

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am writing a report that needs to show the number of bookings taken for a location with the total value of those bookings.

How do I sum the bookings column and show only one row for the location, that includes the columns set out in the example of expected data?

Select Statement Below:

```
SELECT 

Locations.Description as LocationsDesc,
Locations.LocationGUID,
Venues.VenueName,
Venues.VenueGUID,
count (Bookings.BookingID) as Bookings,
Departments.DepartmentName,
Departments.DepartmentGUID,
sum(SalesTransactionDetails.NetDetailValue) as NetDetailValue,
sum(SalesTransactionDetails.DetailValue) as DetailValue,
SUM(CASE When Salestransactionlines.itemtype = 1 Then SalesTransactionDetails.NetDetailValue Else 0 End ) as RentalFee,
SUM(CASE When Salestransactionlines.itemtype = 2 Then SalesTransactionDetails.NetDetailValue Else 0 End ) as ExtraFee,
SalesTransactions.SalesTransactionGUID


FROM   BookingLinesDetails 
INNER JOIN Bookings ON BookingLinesDetails.BookingGUID=Bookings.BookingGUID
INNER JOIN Locations ON BookingLinesDetails.LocationGUID=Locations.LocationGUID
INNER JOIN Venues on Venues.Venueguid = Locations.Venueguid
INNER JOIN SalesTransactionDetails ON BookingLinesDetails.BookingLinesDetailGUID=SalesTransactionDetails.BookingLinesDetailGUID
INNER JOIN SalesTransactionLines ON SalesTransactionDetails.SalesTransactionLineGUID=SalesTransactionLines.SalesTransactionLineGUID 
INNER JOIN SalesTransactions ON SalesTransactionLines.SalesTransactionGUID=SalesTransactions.SalesTransactionGUID
INNER JOIN Departments on Departments.DepartmentGUID = Locations.DepartmentGUID

WHERE  
    BookingLinesDetails.StartDateTime >= dbo.InzDateOnly(@pFromDate) and 
    BookingLinesDetails.StartDateTime < DateAdd(day,1,dbo.inzDateOnly(@pToDate)) and
    Departments.DepartmentGUID in (Select GUID from dbo.InzSplitGUID(@DepartmentID)) and
    (@IncludeAllLocationGroupsInVenues <> 0 or (@IncludeAllLocationGroupsInVenues = 0 )) and
    Venues.VenueGUID in (Select GUID  from dbo.InzSplitGUID(@VenueID)) and
    salesTransactions.Status = 1 and -- remove cancelled
    salestransactions.receiptonly = 0 



GROUP BY 

Locations.Description,
Locations.LocationGUID,
Venues.VenueName,
Venues.VenueGUID,
Departments.DepartmentName,
Departments.DepartmentGUID,
SalesTransactions.SalesTransactionGUID
```

The output is currently:

[image: LocationsDesc MC - Deck Room]

Desired output is:

```
LocationsDesc        LocationGUID   VenueGUID   Bookings    DepartmentName  NetDetailValue  DetailValue ExtraFee
Location - Deck Room    348A43F12   7DAD77BE    33           Aquatics Centre    2059.46      2162.5 0
```

I have attempted several versions of Count and sum.  I believe I need to make the query a derived table and then select from that, but am not sure how to go about it, even if that is the answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the schema look like?

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have access to how the schema is set up

Comment: Remove `SalesTransactions.SalesTransactionGUID` from `select` and `group by` lists maybe?

Comment: that worked thanks, thought I had tried that, but obviously only removed it from select statement.